# android: NeighboringCellInfo always empty !? why?

Tags: android, cell, gsm

i'm trying to get info about the neighboring cells my phone can "see" atm. so far so good. i do this like this:

```
telManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
//...
ArrayList<NeighboringCellInfo> neighboringCellList = (ArrayList<NeighboringCellInfo>) telManager.getNeighboringCellInfo();
```

unfortunately, this list turns out to be empty all the time. even in different places. i live in berlin, so i don't think it's because there is actually just the one cell available!

update:
my permissions look like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem yet? I am on Galaxy Nexus. I have tried all the suggestions below, but I still do not receive anything in the neighboring cells.

Comment: well it seems to be a problem with all Samsung devices. The same code returns the correct results on other devices...

Comment: getNeighboringCellInfo() is deprecated and you should don't use of that .

Answer (score 3):

I've seen several questions on the same issue but it seems like none of them got a good and deterministic solution. The most common suggestion is to make sure you have the correct permission (which I see you do in your question) and there are some that say that this only works on 2G and not 3G.

Take a look at the following similar questions. It might point you in some new directions:

[getNeighboringCellInfo() returning null list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536705/getneighboringcellinfo-returning-null-list)

[Null Issue with NeighboringCellInfo, CID and LAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868223/problem-with-neighboringcellinfo-cid-and-lac)

[Get neighboring cell in Android returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096754/get-neighboring-cell-in-android-returns-null)

Answer (score 1):

`getNeighboringCellInfo()` is deprecated in android . You should use `getAllCellInfo()` and save output of that in a `List` and using a loop on each element of List decide which is neighbor using `element.isRegistered()` .
NeighboringCells have `isRegistered() == false` .