# Getting neighboring cells information using android Samsung galaxy smartphones

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, cells

My target is to get all neighboring cell towers information like cell id, cell lac and RSS values, I used the class `telephonyManager.getNeighboringCellInfo()` to get required information but it return null every time.

But, I succeeded to get the nearest single cell tower information which connected to mobile (i.e serving cell) using `telephonyManager.getCellLocation()`.

I tried to fix this problem and searched on every thing related it, then we found that all samsung devices can not support `telephonyManager.getNeighboringCellInfo()` class and it does not apply on Samsung but its working on HTC and LG devices.

See this: 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24136

I need to apply it on Samsung Android devices and getting neighboring cells information. Can anyone tell me how I can do that?

Single cell code:

```
if (telephonyManager.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM) {
            cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation)telephonyManager.getCellLocation();
            if(cellLocation!=null){
                int cell_ID = cellLocation.getCid();
                int cell_psc= cellLocation.getPsc();
                int cell_lac =cellLocation.getLac();
                cell_info.setText("Cell_ID: "+ String.valueOf(cell_ID) +"\n"+"Cell_psc: "+ String.valueOf(cell_psc)+"\n"+
                        "Cell_lac: " +String.valueOf(cell_lac)+"\n"+cellLocation.toString());

            }
        }
```

neighboring cell code:

```
List<NeighboringCellInfo> neighboringCellInfos = telephonyManager.getNeighboringCellInfo();
        for(NeighboringCellInfo neighboringCellInfo : neighboringCellInfos)
        {
            neighboringCellInfo.getCid();
            neighboringCellInfo.getLac();
            neighboringCellInfo.getPsc();
            neighboringCellInfo.getNetworkType();
            neighboringCellInfo.getRssi();

            neibouring_cell_information.add(neighboringCellInfo.getCid()+"\n"+ neighboringCellInfo.getRssi());

        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),neibouring_cell_information +"ok" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

all added permissions:

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Check this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096754/get-neighboring-cell-in-android-returns-null?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096754/get-neighboring-cell-in-android-returns-null?rq=1) It seems that some mobiles are not supporting.
try to run the same code on different mobile.

Comment: Also, another post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868223/null-issue-with-neighboringcellinfo-cid-and-lac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868223/null-issue-with-neighboringcellinfo-cid-and-lac) someone said it is working in 3G but not working in 2G. Can you confirm this scenario?

Comment: Thanx Aymen: i checked those links before but with no solution, i think its impossible to get neighboring cell information on Samsung                                      devices, can any one give us the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems Samsung phones not supporting neighbor display. Please check this forum:

http://www.finetopix.com/showthread.php?30787-G-NetTrack-Android-OS-Netmonitor/page2

The developer of this app said that samsung chips not supporting commands for display neighbors.

Answer (score 2):

As @Ayman said most of samsung phones and also some other phones not support getNeigbouringCells()

The cellid implementation varies from mobile device to mobile device since these features are considered to be optional. for example:

Samsung (all devices): getNeigbouringCells () is not supported at all and always returns an empty list.

according to this: http://wiki.opencellid.org/wiki/Android_library

and this:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=24306