# What exactly is a NeighboringCell in android.

Tags: android, android-studio, telephonymanager

What exactly is a NeighboringCell in android.

Comment: Have a look to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444703/getting-neighboring-cells-information-using-android-samsung-galaxy-smartphones

Answer (score 1):

From android developer documentation :

> List   getAllCellInfo()
>
> Returns all observed cell information from all radios on the device
>   including the primary and neighboring cells.

So, basically, Neighboring Cell is unused radio signal by your 2 sim card.

Comment: cell is radio signal provided by cell tower